# Access “Popular Near Me” data from Appstore

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to retrieve the “popular near me” list for a given location (except for going there and looking at the phone)?

Perhaps some undocumented parameter to https://rss.itunes.apple.com?

*edit: I am not trying to do this inside an iOS app.*

Comment: Apps that using undocumented parameters, API, functions will be rejected from App Store.

Comment: Clarification: I am not trying to do this from within an app

Comment: I see. You can try to capture the network request (hope it's not encrypted) by Wireshark, maybe?

Comment: @Raptor Always worth trying. I'll post the result here if I succeed!